# Android webview can't show images in Angular page

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm Opening an angular page in a webview, but when it loads the images are not showing but the text elements are complete.

I'm trying enable javascript, domstorage and appcache but arent working.

```
  webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.load_url_web_view);
  WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
  webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
  webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
  webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
  webView.loadUrl(url);
```